Database schema for project management app
As a side project, I'm developing a desktop app for project management, especially for students, self-employed, freelancers, etc. as a general purpose productivity tool, not from any business or industrial perspective. The idea is to create projects/goals/missions and break them down into individual milestones and tasks, and then keep tracking them as they are getting done.
If it takes off, I have other features planned too like embedded notes, tree view for brainstorming items, MCQ puzzles, quote of the day, etc. But for the core project-milestone tracking, this is what I've come up with so far in sqlite:
drop table if exists projects;
drop table if exists milestones;
drop table if exists tasks;
drop table if exists timesheet;
-- drop table if exists notes;
-- drop table if exists mindmaps;
-- drop table if exists mcq;


create table projects (
    id integer primary key,
    status text, -- (Pending/WIP/Complete)
    name text, -- Learn to use Vim Editor
    category text, -- (Work/Study/Other)
    tags text, -- (Tech/PHP/Python/Emacs/Vim)
    start_date datetime,
    end_date datetime,
    notes text
);

create table milestones (
    id integer primary key,
    project_id int references projects(id),
    name text, -- Vim first steps
    status text,
    tags text
);

create table tasks (
    id integer primary key,
    milestone_id int references milestones(id),
    name text, -- hands on with vimtutor
    status text,
    tags text,
    weekly_hrs int, -- no. of hours to be spend on this task each week.
    notes text
);

create table timesheet (
    id integer primary key,
    task_id int references tasks(id),
    fdate datetime,
    tdate datetime, -- tracked 60 minutes
    notes text
);

-- @todo mcq/mindmaps/notes

The tracking will be done by the frontend desktop app I will code separately in Python using tkinter library. Can you suggest me any improvements in this?

not null
As a general rule of thumb, I always encourage folks
designing a new schema to automatically tack on
a NOT NULL column constraint.
Sometimes it will prove to be a mistake,
in which case you can easily remove it.
It's easier to go in that direction,
than to insert many rows in a perhaps somewhat sloppy way
and then want to go back to clean them up and impose the constraint.
If a column value is (or should be) always available,
then JOINs can be easier to author and understand,
plus it may affect the query plan.
And while the machine is good at tri-valued logic,
humans tend to do better with two-valued booleans,
so fewer NULL results from equality checks
tends to make it easier to reason about your evolving system.
FK
These look great:
    project_id   int references projects(id),
    ...
    milestone_id int references milestones(id),

names
Your snake_case identifiers look terrific, thank you.
Not many abbrevs (e.g. weekly_hrs), so that's good.
You're in the "give plural names to tables" camp,
while I'm in the "singular name" camp,
but that's OK, we can still be friends.
I found this pair of names obscure:
    fdate datetime,
    tdate datetime, -- tracked 60 minutes

Maybe they should be from and to?
Or better, start and end?
    start_date datetime,
    end_date   datetime,

I tend to be skeptical about such identifiers.
If it is a TEXT column that might hold '2024-06-25',
then I know how to reason about it, assuming
the projects being managed happen within some restricted
range of longitudes and are mostly worked on when the sun is shining.
But here? Perhaps I should assume midnight timestamps like
'2024-06-25 00:00:00'? And in what timezone?
I recommend you elide the _date suffix,
and simply call them start & end.
The column type makes it clear they are timestamps.
UTC
I always recommend that timestamps shall be persisted on disk as UTC,
typically a number of seconds since the January 1970 epoch.
Computing systems get hooked up to the Internet,
which spans multiple timezones.
Worry about zone offsets on the way in, and on the way out.
enum
These appear to be enumerated categories:

(Pending / WIP / Complete)
(Work / Study / Other)
(Tech / PHP / Python / Emacs / Vim)

Different RDBMS vendors address the topic of Enums in different ways.
One can always throw them into a table which we JOIN against and have
FK
relationships with.
This seems to be the appropriate path for the tags column,
as the set of valid tags shall inevitably keep growing
after you publish some release of the software.
For something more static like status,
you likely want to impose a sqlite
CHECK
constraint.
If nothing else it will minimize case confusion
about 'Pending' versus 'pending'.
namespace
I see three different tags columns, and it's not clear to me
that they are drawn from a common namespace.
Which suggests app developer confusion down the road.
If they are, then use an FK REFERENCES clause to highlight that.
Otherwise, you might want to clarify that they are distinct,
calling them project tags, milestone tags, and status tags.
searching
Typically a column identifier will be singular,
modeling one thing in the real world.
Since you wrote plural tags, I assume that you'll
have some kind of comma-delimited text in there such as "emacs,python".
Please understand that someone searching for all python-tagged
entries will be forced to tablescan the whole table.
But wouldn't we like to exploit the indexing strengths of an RDBMS?
Model this with a many-to-many table so
you can index it.
This will improve your "search" query plans.
comments
Thank you for this helpful comment:
    weekly_hrs int, -- no. of hours to be spent on this task each week.

I'm not saying you should rename the identifier.
I will just observe that weekly_hrs made me think
of an "actual reported effort" figure recorded after-the-fact,
while in contrast the comment makes me think of a prospective
"budgeting" forecast.
As an orthogonal modeling detail, suppose that effort for
a certain project was limited to just participating in
a 30-minute weekly status meeting.
Then the INTEGER type would be trouble.
